# Spark sql querying a Hive table from workers

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to querying a Hive table from a map operation in Spark, but when it run a query the execution getting frozen.

This is my test code

```
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val datasetPath = "npiCodesMin.csv"
val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()

val df = sparkSession.read.option("header", true).option("sep", ",").csv(datasetPath)
df.createOrReplaceTempView("npicodesTmp")
sparkSession.sql("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS npicodes");
sparkSession.sql("CREATE TABLE npicodes AS SELECT * FROM npicodesTmp");

val res = sparkSession.sql("SELECT * FROM npicodes WHERE NPI = '1588667638'") //This works
println(res.first())

val NPIs = sc.parallelize(List("1679576722", "1588667638", "1306849450", "1932102084"))//Some existing NPIs

val rows = NPIs.mapPartitions{ partition =>
  val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
  partition.map{code =>
    val res = sparkSession.sql("SELECT * FROM npicodes WHERE NPI = '"+code+"'")//The program stops here
    res.first()
  }
}

rows.collect().foreach(println)
```

It loads the data from a CSV, creates a new Hive table and fills it with the CSV data.
Then, if I query the table from the master it works perfectly, but if I try to do that in a map operation the execution getting frozen.
It do not generate any error, it continue running without do anything.

The Spark UI shows this situation
[image: Spark UI]

Actually, I am not sure if I can query a table in a distributed way, I cannot find it in the documentation.
Any suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this code? return a random row based on the NPI column?
Starting a SparkSession is generally not a viable option - would be better to refactor this to use a Window with a partition on NDI, e.g. using `firstValue`

Comment: NPI is the identifier, anyway, yes, I'm just trying to get a record using the NPI column. It's just a test, to see if this procedure works.

My problem is to perform the similarity between records, I already have the possible couples of ids as an RDD of (id1,id2), but I need to get the full records in order to provide them to the similarity function.
Send the records in broadcast is not possible, because they are to big, so I thought to use spark sql to store the records and read them from the workers.

Comment: I would suggest you use spark-sql throughout, and just do your transformations on the dataframe/-set you obtained from reading the csv file. If you do that, all queries will already be distributed on executors and there is nothing extra to do. Or, if you need to work with RDDs for some reason, you can still select what you need from the Dataframe, then convert it to an RDD[Row]. Either way, I cannot think of a reason why you would need to do  a select within a mapPartitions call here.